# How to activate native bootstrap 2.3.2 javascript components in Liferay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I am using Liferay 6.2 and including Alloy UI's version of Bootstrap in my html pages, i.e:

```
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.5.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.5.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
```

I would like to make use of Bootstrap's responsive navbar in my html like the example on the  [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) but this requires the jquery collapse plugin to be included but my boss has told us we cannot include jquery and must solely use YUI. I know Alloy UI includes several Bootstrap equivalent jquery components such as Modal, TabView, Accordion, etc. But I cannot get a mobile reponsive navbar working. Is there a workaround to plumb this feauture in without adding jQuery and Bootstrap as a Module within YUI?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve resposiveness for liferay theme you don't need the js part of bootstrap.

Lifery 6.2 include Bootstrap 2.3 without the js part, it's not useful to have a responsive nav-bar, it's a css only matter.

Classic theme is responsive, copy from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this javascript code for showing/hiding responsive navbar menu with AlloyUI, without using jQuery/collapse. Seems to work fine with Android/iOS default browser.

```
YUI().use(
    'aui-node',
    function (Y) {
        var navbarButton = Y.one(".btn-navbar");
        var navbarCollapse = Y.one(".nav-collapse");

        navbarButton.on('click', function (e) {
            if (navbarCollapse.hasClass("in")) {
                navbarCollapse.removeClass("in");
                navbarCollapse.setStyle("height", "0px");
            } else {
                navbarCollapse.addClass("in");
                navbarCollapse.setStyle("height", "auto");
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Also, I'm setting up responsive navbar with this code. I modified original example removing `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes from navbar button.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <a class="btn btn-navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if this is enough for you case.